# PHP + FTP delete files in folder

Tags: php, ftp, delete-file

I just wrote a PHP Script which should connect to  FTP and delete all files in a special folder.

It looks like this, but I have no clue what command I need to delete all files in the folder logs.

Any idea?

```
<?php

// set up the settings
$ftp_server = 'something.net';
$ftpuser = 'username';
$ftppass = 'pass';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppass);

// delete all files in the folder logs
????????

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
// Delete all files in the folder logs
$logs_dir = "";
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $logs_dir);
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    ftp_delete($conn_id, $file);
}
```

You might want to do some checking for directories, but at a basic level, that is it.

Comment: @Lukas: damn, I even double checked that foreach was the syntax beforehand. xD Thanks for the catch.  /Edited

Comment: is there any where to specify specific file extensions to delete like *.jpg?

Answer (score 4):

The [PHP manual on the FTP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) has the answers.

- [`ftp_nlist()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) to list
- [`ftp_delete()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-delete.php) to delete

the user contributed notes give [full examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#62306) for a "delete folder" function. (Handle with care.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

# server credentials
$host = "ftp server";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";

# connect to ftp server
$handle = @ftp_connect($host) or die("Could not connect to {$host}");

# login using credentials
@ftp_login($handle, $user, $pass) or die("Could not login to {$host}");

function recursiveDelete($directory)
{
# here we attempt to delete the file/directory
if( !(@ftp_rmdir($handle, $directory) || @ftp_delete($handle, $directory)) )
{
# if the attempt to delete fails, get the file listing
$filelist = @ftp_nlist($handle, $directory);

# loop through the file list and recursively delete the FILE in the list
foreach($filelist as $file)
{
recursiveDelete($file);
}

#if the file list is empty, delete the DIRECTORY we passed
recursiveDelete($directory);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my FTP recursive delete directory solution:

```
/**
 * @param string $directory
 * @param resource $connection
 */
function deleteDirectoryRecursive(string $directory, $connection)
{
    if (@ftp_delete($connection, $directory)) {
        // delete file
        return;
    }
    # here we attempt to delete the file/directory
    if( !@ftp_rmdir($connection, $directory) )
    {
        if ($files = @ftp_nlist ($connection, $directory)) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                // delete file or directory
                deleteDirectoryRecursive( $file, connection);
            }
        }
    }
    @ftp_rmdir($connection, $directory);
}
```