# How to delete all files and folders on FTP?

Tags: file, ftp, directory, delete-file

Is there a way to delete all files and folders on ftp by one click with using php? I searched by google and stackoverflow but there are no results for the all files, just for single file or folder. So can anyone help me about this?

Comment: I think you would need to use mdelete to delete all files, then iterate over the directories and call rmdir on them

Answer (score 1):

There's no way in FTP to delete a directory recursively using a single command. If that's what you mean by *"one click"*.

You have to recursively list folder and delete files and subfolders one-by-one.

For that see:
[Delete folder and all files on FTP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513605/850848)