# How can I use this function?

Tags: php

```
function ftpDeleteDirectory($directory)
{
    global $conn_id;
    if(empty($directory))//Validate that a directory was sent, otherwise will delete ALL files/folders
        return json_encode(false);
    else{
        # here we attempt to delete the file/directory
        if( !(@ftp_rmdir($conn_id,$directory) || @ftp_delete($conn_id,$directory)) )
        {
            # if the attempt to delete fails, get the file listing
            $filelist = @ftp_nlist($conn_id, $directory);
            # loop through the file list and recursively delete the FILE in the list
            foreach($filelist as $file)
            {
            //  return json_encode($filelist);
                ftpDeleteDirectory($directory.'/'.$file);/***THIS IS WHERE I MUST RESEND ABSOLUTE PATH TO FILE***/
            }

            #if the file list is empty, delete the DIRECTORY we passed
            ftpDeleteDirectory($directory);
        }
    }
    return json_encode(true);
};
```

How can I use this function written about ftp?
Trying to add the ability to delete a Folder using FTP and all subfolders and files contained within that folder.

Comment: 1. ftp commands can only be executed AFTER you have logged in the ftp server thru valid username and password. 2. Refer to this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rmdir.php) too

Comment: No, I know that, I just want to see how I can use the above functions (how to execute the above functions?)

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke a function in PHP?